# Error "Cannot open clipboard"

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

I am running Windows 10.  A few weeks ago, applications at random give me this message when I try to copy something to / from the clipboard.

> Cannot open clipboard

[image: Cannot Open Clipboard]

If I reboot, then the same application works.  Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: lbview isn't a standard application.  Does this happen in Safe Mode.  You clearly have an application that is causing this problem.  Use Autoruns to determine which application it is

Comment: That's an example.  It has nothing to do with a particular application.  Different ones exhibit it at different times.  None of these applications are newly installed.  And they used to work fine.

Comment: Do the rest of my suggestion.

Comment: Check this Clipboard Debugging program here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/copy-past-error-connot-open-the-clipboard-excel/08f69f94-9638-4376-9469-ca2c9ffdec37 Should tell you which program is locking the Clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

**Repair office**

1. Run(Ctrl + R): appwiz.cpl
2. Right click on Microsoft office
3. Click repair
4. Reboot and test